# Passing function to child reac

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react. I try to propagate information from child to parent component:

**Parent**:

```
export default function App() {
  const [isLoading, setisLoading] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isLoading ? <LoadingView/> :  <MainView SetStateOfLoading={setisLoading}/>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Child:**

```
export default function GetInformation(SetStateOfLoading) {  
   
   
   console.log(typeof SetStateOfLoading);
   SetStateOfLoading();
   console.log("SetStateOfLoading run");

    return (
        <h2>This supposed to be main view </h2>
    );
}
```

I get on this the error that `SetStateOfLoading is not a function`?

Thanks, I edited the code to:

```
export default function GetInformation({SetStateOfLoading}) {
```

Why I get this warning:

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`GetInformation`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `GetInformation`, follow the stack trace as described in https: 
 //fb.me  /setstate-in-render
    in GetInformation (at App.js:16)
    in div (at App.js:15)
    in App (at src/index.js:9)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)
```

?

In my first little projet, I want to have a button, when sombody click on it the we called to some function that do some calculation.
I want that when we go in the function the screen will change to Loading animation, and when I leave the function we will get for the formar screen.

What is the correct way of doing this in react?

Comment: What do you mean? this is the Paernt

Answer (score 1):

you are mistake here,

```
export default function GetInformation(SetStateOfLoading) {
```

instead, you probaly meant,

```
export default function GetInformation({ SetStateOfLoading }) {
```

jsx tags are passed with object containing the attributes as its first argument.

see https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: @development pls, mark as answer & upvote if it helped

Answer (score 0):

your child should be like this

```
export default function GetInformation(props) {  


  console.log(typeof props.SetStateOfLoading);
   props.SetStateOfLoading();
  console.log("SetStateOfLoading run");

return (
    <h2>This supposed to be main view </h2>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just did a common mistake people new to react make.

React component takes props as `Object`.

```
export default function GetInformation({ SetStateOfLoading }) {} // Object de-structuring
```

**or to make it clear**

```
export default function GetInformation({ props}) {
 const SetStateOfLoading = props.SetStateOfLoading;
}
```